# Jenkins Pipeline General Build Step - Pass value dynamically

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to automate a build scanner (Acunetix) step via Jenkins Pipeline and the input to the BuildScanner needs to be sent as a variable:

```groovy
id="abdcefg"
step([$class: 'BuildScanner', incScan: false, incScanId: '', profile: '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111', stopScan: true, svRep: true, target: $id, threat: 'DoNotFail'])
```

General build step doesn't take arguments dynamically or is there a different way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The `$` sign in front of an argument is an error. It is only necessary for string interpolation, but not when you use a variable directly.

> ```groovy
> target: $id
> ```

This should work:

```groovy
id="abdcefg" 
step([$class: 'BuildScanner', incScan: false, incScanId: '', profile: '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111', stopScan: true, svRep: true, target: id, threat: 'DoNotFail'])
```

Comment: Thanks.. but the step takes value as id and not the value stored in the variable id

Comment: @BenSG I'm not sure I understand. Can you post a link to the documentation?

Comment: Identified this as an issue with the plugin build and fixing it helps to work